# Are there reasons that Javascript can only access some of the new DOM after Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I am just learning JS and while implementing AJAX I ran into some strange behavior.

In my code I have the following

`<div id="saved_listing_form"></div>`

an `onchange` in a select element runs a script where ajax fills the above div with a preview of the saved listing along with a form populated with fields that can be edited in order to edit the listing if desired.

There is a button in the form that is used to preview the changes to the listing before saving them.

Below is the code that will be populated by the "preview" script that does not respond to JS

```
           <article class="listing" id="listing_preview" style="display:none;" title="">
             <a href="" id="preview_url" target="_blank"><img id="preview_picture" src="" alt=""><h3 id="preview_name"></h3>
                <span id="preview_phone"></span><address><span id="preview_address_1"></span><br><span id="preview_address_2"></span>
                <span id="preview_city_state_zip"></span></address>
             </a>
           </article>
```

I tried manipulating the listing through the console in Firefox as a last resort.  The console is able to find the article,

`document.getElementById('listing_preview')`

but cannot produce changes in the DOM

`document.getElementById('listing_preview').style.display = 'block';`

will not make it appear

I can even

make changes to the object in the console, but that will not show up on the page.
ie `document.getElementById('preview_name').innerHTML = 'Hello';`

This change will show up in the console, but not in the page.

Here is the strange part.  The already-saved listing that is populated by ajax in the saved_listing_form works perfectly and can be manipulated via the console and scripts as expected.

`<article class="listing" id="listing" title="Dr. Peter Griffin of Q'Hog, RI"><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"><img id="saved_image" src="images/clients/Peter_Griffin20200827180833.jpg"><h3>Peter  Griffin, D.C.</h3>+11234567890<br><address>123 Spooner St<br>Q'Hog, RI 12345</address></a></article>`

Are there any reasons that part of the ajax-populated div works as expected while other DOM objects within the same div would not?  I don't appear to have any broken html elements that would throw things off.

The reference to the JS that controls the preview is loaded in at the very end of the code that ajax populates.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Basic problem is you can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by definition. `getElementById()` will always return the first if there are duplicates as it does not expect there to be more than one

Comment: Yep make sure your id are unique or use document.getElementsByClassName() to modify all elements matching a specific class

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies. That was exactly the problem.  I had already completed another part of the page and had the display set to none, so I kind of forgot about it.  In addition to that, in Firefox when you Right Click and view page source the newly ajaxed content does not show up so when searching that I did not see the duplicate id's.  It was only when I went back to the code itself looking at the php includes is where I found it.  Thank you so much for the tip!!